# Passing a string as a sortable parameter to use in a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am trying to achieve a dynamic way of ordering my database results by a string parameter passed into my controller `sortByColumn` but I cannot see how I would change `OrderBy` to allow for this. I guess I would need some kind of evaluation function? Is there a better way?

```
public ViewResult List(int page = 1, string? sortByColumn = null)
{
    JamesListViewModel model = new JamesListViewModel
    {
        James = repository.James
            //.OrderBy(s => s.Name)
            .OrderBy(s => s.sortByColumn) // This line is junk :(
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = repository.James.Count()
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Maybe [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) will help you here.

Comment: Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: What is `repository`? There is no single technique that you can use with all LINQ providers. Even Dynamic LINQ is not really supported by Microsoft as it was more of a Sample than a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of using [*Dynamic LINQ*](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) which would definitely help, you could build a simple `switch` statement covering all columns of `James` on which you plan to sort, like this:

```
var james = repository.James;
switch (sortByColumn)
{
    case "Name": james = james.OrderBy(s => s.Name); break;
    case "Age": james = james.OrderBy(s => s.Age); break;
    case "Strength": james = james.OrderBy(s => s.Strength); break;
    // No default: if sortByColumn is null or unknown, the result is unordered
}
JamesListViewModel model = new JamesListViewModel
{
    James = james
        .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize),
    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
    {
        CurrentPage = page,
        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
        TotalItems = repository.James.Count()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with reflection,

```
James = repository.James
        .OrderBy(s =>s.GetType().GetProperty(sortByColumn).GetValue(s,null))
        .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
        .Take(PageSize)
```

Comment: This won't work with LINQ to EF/NHibernate or another ORM that try to convert the LINQ query to a SQL statement. In LINQ to SQL it will load everything on the client and tryp to sorting and page there using LINQ to Objects. There is no generic solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
public IEnumerable GetJames(int page = 1, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,)
{ 
      var query = repository.James;
       //other stuff
      if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }

}
```

And use it like

```
public ActionView List()
{
   var model =   GetJames(orderBy: q => q.OrderBy(d => d.Name));
}
```

The code above is not functional it just gives you a context on what you could do.

Comment: The question is about string query parameter, and in your case you are using Expression. It's not the same.

Comment: Why pass the entire OrderBy expression instead of just the lambda?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov I know it's not the same... I just find it a better solution to achieve the ordering requirement than a string which you have to make sure you pass correctly (especially if yo exposing it to third parties).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you could pass the just the lamda expression but then what if you needed to have DESC and ASC ordering?

Comment: That wasn't in the question, and can be easily fixed by passing a boolean parameter to let you pick OrderBy or OrderByDescending. Your signature method makes stronger demands on the repository than Enumerable.OrderBy or Queryable.OrderBy

Comment: I don't think that passing additional parameters (like a boolean parameter) is the optimal solution. In general I would avoid passing more parameters than necessary. I am not sure what you mean by stronger demands than Queryable.OrderBy. If you mean what `TEntity` implies then this is easily fixed. If you mean something else please elaborate.

Comment: Eg, you are assuming the repository is a Queryable. What if it is an IEnumerable? Or what if it only implements IQueryable? OrderBy only wants a Func<TSource,TKey>

Comment: I am assuming that the repository is IQueryable and returns IOrderedQueryable. IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable and IQueryable is a very logical assumption given that the question talks about a database. Of course if for some reason IEnumerable is what you need you can either downcast (ugly) or change it the signature to something suitable. The whole point of the answer is the way to pass ordering parameters. It's a good think you brought up those concerns however.